# Need 3 point-correspondences to determine a rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I read somewhere that you need three correspondences (pairs of points) to uniquely determine a rotation. How do you prove this? I'm only aware of making similar arguments when considering the solution $x$ for $Ax=b$. But in this case, we have $Rv=v'$ for a rotation matrix R.

Comment: What is the exact statement you want to prove, stated precisely?

Comment: Rotation 1) Around the origin (Yes, No) ? 2) 2D or 3D ?

Comment: 1) I am referring to points on an object which is being rotated about its center of mass (its local origin). 2) in 3D

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have three non-collinear, non-zero points $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{w}$, a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$, and three non-collinear, non-zero points $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, and $\vec{k}$, such that
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
\vec{u} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{i} \\
\vec{v} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{j} \\
\vec{w} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{k} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
By non-collinear, non-zero points, I mean a tetrahedron with vertices at the three vectors and fourth at origin has nonzero volume.

If we write
$$\vec{u} = \left[\begin{matrix}u_x\\u_y\\u_z\end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{v} = \left[\begin{matrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{w} = \left[\begin{matrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{i} = \left[\begin{matrix}i_x\\i_y\\i_z\end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{j} = \left[\begin{matrix}j_x\\j_y\\j_z\end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{k} = \left[\begin{matrix}k_x\\k_y\\k_z\end{matrix}\right]$$
and $$\mathbf{R} = \left[\begin{matrix} R_{xx} & R_{yx} & R_{zx} \\ R_{xy} & R_{yy} & R_{zy} \\ R_{xz} & R_{yz} & R_{zz} \end{matrix} \right]$$
then in Cartesian coordinate form $\eqref{G1}$ is equivalent to
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
u_x &= R_{xx} i_x + R_{yx} i_y + R_{zx} i_z \\
u_y &= R_{xy} i_x + R_{yy} i_y + R_{zy} i_z \\
u_z &= R_{xz} i_x + R_{yz} i_y + R_{zz} i_z \\
v_x &= R_{xx} j_x + R_{yx} j_y + R_{zx} j_z \\
v_y &= R_{xy} j_x + R_{yy} j_y + R_{zy} j_z \\
v_z &= R_{xz} j_x + R_{yz} j_y + R_{zz} j_z \\
w_x &= R_{xx} k_x + R_{yx} k_y + R_{zx} k_z \\
w_y &= R_{xy} k_x + R_{yy} k_y + R_{zy} k_z \\
w_z &= R_{xz} k_x + R_{yz} k_y + R_{zz} k_z \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{2}\label{G2}$$
which is a system of nine linear equations in nine unknowns, and has a single solution,
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
R_{xx} &= \frac{ w_x (i_y j_z - i_z j_y) + v_x (i_z k_y - i_y k_z) + u_x (j_y k_z - j_z k_y) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{yx} &= \frac{ w_x (i_z j_x - i_x j_z) + v_x (i_x k_z - i_z k_x) + u_x (j_z k_x - j_x k_z) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{zx} &= \frac{ w_x (i_x j_y - i_y j_x) + v_x (i_y k_x - i_x k_y) + u_x (j_x k_y - j_y k_x) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{xy} &= \frac{ w_y (i_y j_z - i_z j_y) + v_y (i_z k_y - i_y k_z) + u_y (j_y k_z - j_z k_y) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{yy} &= \frac{ w_y (i_z j_x - i_x j_z) + v_y (i_x k_z - i_z k_x) + u_y (j_z k_x - j_x k_z) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{zy} &= \frac{ w_y (i_x j_y - i_y j_x) + v_y (i_y k_x - i_x k_y) + u_y (j_x k_y - j_y k_x) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{xz} &= \frac{ w_z (i_y j_z - i_z j_y) + v_z (i_z k_y - i_y k_z) + u_z (j_y k_z - j_z k_y) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{yz} &= \frac{ w_z (i_z j_x - i_x j_z) + v_z (i_x k_z - i_z k_x) + u_z (j_z k_x - j_x k_z) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
R_{zz} &= \frac{ w_z (i_x j_y - i_y j_x) + v_z (i_y k_x - i_x k_y) + u_z (j_x k_y - j_y k_x) }{ i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) } \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{3}\label{G3}$$
Note that the common divisor is the triple product, $\vec{i} \cdot \vec{j} \times \vec{k}$.  This is zero if the volume of a tetrahedron with vertices at $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, $\vec{k}$, and origin, is zero.

Comment: Your formulas would be simpler if you give a name $\delta= i_x ( j_y k_z - j_z k_y ) + i_y ( j_z k_x - j_x k_z ) + i_z ( j_x k_y - j_y k_x ) $ to the common denominator.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Absolutely true, and I even looked at having just $D$ as the common denominator, with a final $D = \vec{i} \cdot \vec{j} \times \vec{k}$ in the system describing it, but I just didn't like how it looked!  Sorry! :-)

Comment: (@JeanMarie and anyone else: If there is a better term describing the restriction on the three vectors $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, $\vec{k}$ (and through the rotation, the corresponding other set of vectors) than the volume of a tetrahedron with vertices corresponding to those vectors and the origin not being zero – i.e. that $\vec{i}\cdot\vec{j}\times\vec{k} \ne 0$ –, then do please edit it in. I do not know a simple but correct term to use here, nor how to express it better.)

Comment: @Glärbo Can you explain how you came up with the constraint that the vertices cannot form a tetrahedron

Comment: @user3180: No, no, the opposite:  If you use the three points and the origin to form a tetrahedron, **its volume must not be zero**.  You see, the volume $V$ of such a tetrahedron is by definition $$V = \frac{1}{6}\left\lvert \vec{i} \cdot \vec{j} \times \vec{k} \right\rvert$$See the triple product in there?  The solution for matrix $\mathbf{R}$ only exists when the common denominator – that same triple product! – is nonzero.  So, by talking about the tetrahedron I was trying to convey the intuitive idea of what kind of triplet of points you need for this to be possible, but [...]

Comment: [...] the mathematical reason is just that we need the triple product between the three points to be nonzero for the solution for matrix $\mathbf{R}$ to exist.  The cases where the tetrahedron volume *would* be zero are when the three points are collinear, one of them is a zero vector (i.e., at origin), or when all three of those points are coplanar with origin.  (I might be missing some cases, though; these are the obvious ones.)  In these cases, the tetrahedron is *degenerate*: planar, a line segment, or a point.  And in all these cases, the triple product is obviously zero [...]

Comment: [...] because the volume of a degenerate tetrahedron is zero.  (A plane does not have any volume, nor does a line segment, nor a point, to say it another way.)

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\begin{cases}
\vec{u'} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{u} \\
\vec{v'} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{v} \\
\vec{w'} &= \mathbf{R} \vec{w} \\
\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

with

$$\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix}u_x\\u_y\\u_z\end{pmatrix}, ~
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{pmatrix}, ~
\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{pmatrix}, ~
\vec{u'} = \begin{pmatrix}u'_x\\u'_y\\u'_z\end{pmatrix}, ~
\vec{v'} = \begin{pmatrix}v'_x\\v'_y\\v'_z\end{pmatrix}, ~
\vec{w'} = \begin{pmatrix}w'_x\\w'_y\\w'_z\end{pmatrix}$$

That you can write under a matricial form:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} u'_{x} & v'_{x} & w'_{x} \\  u'_{y} & v'_{y} & w'_{y} \\  u'_{z} & v'_{z} & w'_{z} \end{pmatrix}}_{B^{\ \prime}}=R \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} u_{x} & v_{x} & w_{x} \\  u_{y} & v_{y} & w_{y} \\  u_{z} & v_{z} & w_{z} \end{pmatrix}}_B$$

giving

$$R=B^{\ \prime}B^{-1}\tag{2}$$

which in fact gives the unique linear application mapping

$$\vec{u} \ \text{onto} \ \vec{u'}, ~
\vec{v} \ \text{onto} \ \vec{v'}, ~
\vec{w}  \ \text{onto} \  \vec{w'}$$

which will be a rotation if the distance and orientation conditions are met.

Remark: The equations of @Glärbo express relationship (2) in a detailed manner.

Comment: Any comment ?... Have you remarked there is no "a priori": we don't assume in any way that we have a rotation matrix... If there is some incertitude in the coordinates, there is a way to find the closest rotation matrix to this matrix.